# FIPS 140-2 Compliance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Just wondering if anyone has configured FIPS?  Based on the information I found in the Microsoft support pages, it would seem FIPS is configured at the Windows level only and that all instances on my server would then be enabled for FIPS?

At this point, I am only interested in one of the instances using FIPS.

Everything I have read so far, indicates I may need to split this out  to a new server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, FIPS 140-2 is configured at OS level. You cannot be compliant if the OS itself is not compliant. See [KB2733626: Instructions for using SQL Server 2012 in the FIPS 140-2-compliant mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2733626) (not sure where is the 2014 equivalent).

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the OS part. Just so I'm clear, if configured on the OS, all 3 SQL instances will be FIPS compliant by default? If I only need 1 instance to be FIPS compliant, it needs to be on separate hardware?

Comment: Strictly speaking does not to be separate 'hardware', it can be a separate VM. But yes, once the OS enables FIPS compliance then all instances on that host will run in compliance mode.

Comment: It's what I was assuming but I wanted clarification. Thanks for coming back to me.